# How exactly does the "reflect" mode for scipys ndimage filters work?

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy, filtering

I'm failing to understand exactly how the reflect mode handles my arrays. I have this very simple array:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter
from scipy.ndimage.filters import median_filter

vector = np.array([[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0],[2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0],[4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0],[5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0,5.0]])

print(vector)
```

[[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 4.  4.  4.  4.  4.]
 [ 5.  5.  5.  5.  5.]]

Applying a uniform (mean) filter with a window size of 3 I get the following:

```
filtered = uniform_filter(vector, 3, mode='reflect')

print(filtered)
```

[[ 1.33333333  1.33333333  1.33333333  1.33333333  1.33333333]
 [ 2.33333333  2.33333333  2.33333333  2.33333333  2.33333333]
 [ 3.66666667  3.66666667  3.66666667  3.66666667  3.66666667]
 [ 4.66666667  4.66666667  4.66666667  4.66666667  4.66666667]]

If I try to replicate the exercise by hand I can get to this result. Original matrix in green, window in orange and result in yellow. White are "reflected" observations.

[image]

Result is:

[image]

But when I try a window size of 4 or 5 I fail to be able to replicate the results.

```
filtered = uniform_filter(vector, 4, mode='reflect')

print(filtered)
```

[[ 1.5  1.5  1.5  1.5  1.5]
 [ 2.   2.   2.   2.   2. ]
 [ 3.   3.   3.   3.   3. ]
 [ 4.   4.   4.   4.   4. ]]

Doing it by hand:

[image]

And I get:

[image]

How is the window handled if its size is even? But anyway, If I try to replicate the results of a window of size 5 and mode reflect I cant either. Even though I would think the behavior is analogous to that of size 3.

Comment: In the image below "Doing it by hand:", you didn't fill in the top row of your extended array correctly.  You simply copied the value `1` vertically.  With `mode='reflect'`, there should be `2`s in the top row above the main (bright yellow) array.

Comment: that's exactly what I want to know, can you help me understand exactly how the mode works? for window size n= 2,3,..., etc ? I would accept that as the answer to this, I'm especially interested in know how the windows work when the dimension is an even number.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Suppose the data in one axis is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`.  The following table shows how the data is extended for each mode (assuming `cval=0`):

```
    mode       |   Ext   |         Input          |   Ext
    -----------+---------+------------------------+---------
    'mirror'   | 4  3  2 | 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 | 7  6  5
    'reflect'  | 3  2  1 | 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 | 8  7  6
    'nearest'  | 1  1  1 | 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 | 8  8  8
    'constant' | 0  0  0 | 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 | 0  0  0
    'wrap'     | 6  7  8 | 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8 | 1  2  3
```

For an even window size `n`, consider the window of size `n+1`, and then don't include the lower and right edges.  (The position of the window can be changed by using the `origin` argument.)

Comment: So this happens in every dimensión? so for n=3 (as you are using) 'reflect' on the first column would be '1 1 1', what happens with the diagonal next to the top left '1' ?

Comment: Where is doc for this?

Comment: I found the doc here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/ndimage.html

Comment: @JEquihua diagonals are reflected as well so you have top-left = 1 and top-top-left-left = 2. The current docs explain better than old docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html