# Modes of scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve not understood

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, scipy, convolution

Function `scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve` accept a `mode` parameter for different border-handling schemes:

```
mode : {'reflect','constant','nearest','mirror', 'wrap'}
```

I know about the `imfilter` function in `Matlab`, and assume the follow mapping on the keywords used to describe border-handling schemes:

```
imfilter      convolve

(scalar)      'constant'
'symmetric'   'mirror'
'replicate'   'nearest'
'circular'    'reflect'   ---- Am I right?
```

Questions:

1. Did I get all these correct?
2. What does mode `'wrap'` do?

Comment: Duplicate question; see stackoverflow.com/questions/22669252/how-exactly-does-the-reflect-mode-for-scipys-ndimage-filters-work

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The question itself is not duplicate, but I find answer following your URL. Thanks.

Comment: @FrozenFlame if you've found an answer yourself, you should post/accept it as the correct answer!

Answer (score 2):

The equivalence table is almost correct; the only mistake is "circular", which should be mapped to "wrap"

```
imfilter      convolve

(scalar)      'constant'
'symmetric'   'mirror'
n.a.          'reflect'
'replicate'   'nearest'
'circular'    'wrap'
```

As stated in the table, the "reflect" convolve mode has no matlab equivalent; the most similar is 'symmetric' (they only differ for the fact that the border element is replicated in 'reflect', but not in 'mirror').

References:

- https://mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfilter.html
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669252/