# numpy/scipy complex signal convolution with different boundary options

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, convolution

I am doing some time-domain windowing of 1D frequency domain signals.  The window is defined in the time-domain, but I am doing convolution of the signal and the window in the frequency domain.

`scipy.ndimage` has two functions: `convolve` and `convolve1d` that have a keyword argument `mode` that allows you to specify how the convolution treats the boundaries, where the options are: `reflect, constant, nearest, mirror, wrap` with a nice explanation of those things [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669252/how-exactly-does-the-reflect-mode-for-scipys-ndimage-filters-work?rq=1).
These functions are real-valued only.  Complex numbers not allowed

`scipy.signal` has the `convolve` function which handles complex numbers, but only handles boundaries by padding zeros, which is the `constant` mode in the `scipy.ndimage` convolution functions.

Doing a simple multiplication in the time-domain followed by fft is equivalent to the `wrap` mode of convolution.

How can I do convolution of two 1D complex numpy arrays with different boundary conditions.  Specifically I need the `reflect` mode.

Comment: `ndimage`’s convolution functions probably support those boundary conditions because they’re implemented in the time-domain. Scipy’s does either time-domain or FFT-based frequency-domain convolution, and its output needs to match for both modes—the FFT route is the more limiting because I’m not aware of any FFT library that supports any boundary condition other than `wrap`, since that’s the assumption baked into Fourier theory. I’d just build the `reflect`ed signal manually and convolve them and very carefully take the samples of the output that I want. Makes sense?

Comment: @Ahmed Fasih, Yes it makes sense, but I'm not actually sure how to execute that.