# Dynamically varying the filter size in the scipys ndimage filters

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, filtering, moving-average

Following [How exactly does the “reflect” mode for scipys ndimage filters work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22669252/how-exactly-does-the-reflect-mode-for-scipys-ndimage-filters-work) and [Numpy Two-Dimensional Moving Average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000260/numpy-two-dimensional-moving-average), I have a two dimensional array of:

```
a
=> 
np.array([[ 0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
       [ 15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.]])
```

When I use `mode=constant` and a `3x3 filter size`:

```
uniform_filter(a, size=3, mode='constant')
```

The result is:

```
=> 
array([[  1.33333333,   2.33333333,   3.        ,   3.66666667,          2.66666667],
       [  3.66666667,   6.        ,   7.        ,   8.        ,          5.66666667],
       [  7.        ,  11.        ,  12.        ,  13.        ,          9.        ],
       [ 10.33333333,  16.        ,  17.        ,  18.        ,         12.33333333],
       [  8.        ,  12.33333333,  13.        ,  13.66666667,          9.33333333]])
```

I understand how this filter works internally as it has been well explained in the links I have posted above.

My question is that is it possible to divide, for each position in the array, its sum by the total number of element whose value is greater than zero?

So for example, in my array in position [0,0] where the element is `0`, the sum of the element `(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 6)` would be divided by `3` (only positions [0,1] = `1`, [1,0] = `5` and [1,1] = `6` have values greater than zero) instead of `9`. And in position [0,1] of the array, I would divide by `5`. In position [0,2], I divide by `6` and in position [1,2] I divide by `9`.

In this case, my answer should be;

```
=> 
array([[ 4.0 ,  4.2 ,  4.5 ,  5.5 ,  6.0  ],
       [ 6.60,  6.75,  7.0 ,  8.0 ,  8.5  ],
       [ 10.5,  11. ,  12. ,  13. ,  13.5 ],
       [ 15.5,  16. ,  17. ,  18. ,  18.5 ],
       [ 18.0,  18.5,  19.5,  20.5,  21.0 ]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach -

```
from scipy.ndimage.filters import uniform_filter
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

size = 3       
kernel = np.ones((size,size),dtype=int)  
nonzero_count = convolve2d(a!=0, kernel,'same')
windowed_sum = uniform_filter(a, size=size, mode='constant')*size**2
out = windowed_sum/nonzero_count
```

Steps :

- Get count of non-zeros in sliding windows of shape : `(size,size)` along the rows and columns of input array.
  For this we could use `2D` convolution with a kernel of all `ones` and of the same shape as the kernel. Alternatively we could also get the nonzero counts with `uniform_filter` : `uniform_filter((a!=0).astype(float), size=size, mode='constant')*size**2`.
- Get the sliding summations by re-using the average values from `uniform_filter` output and scaling by `size**2`. Alternatively, we could again use `2D` convolution here with `convolve2d(a, kernel,'same')`.
- Finally, divide those summations by the non-zeros count, which is the desired output.

Sample input, intermediate outputs and final output -

```
In [51]: a
Out[51]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.],
       [ 15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.]])

In [53]: nonzero_count
Out[53]: 
array([[3, 5, 6, 6, 4],
       [5, 8, 9, 9, 6],
       [6, 9, 9, 9, 6],
       [6, 9, 9, 9, 6],
       [4, 6, 6, 6, 4]])

In [54]: windowed_sum
Out[54]: 
array([[  12.,   21.,   27.,   33.,   24.],
       [  33.,   54.,   63.,   72.,   51.],
       [  63.,   99.,  108.,  117.,   81.],
       [  93.,  144.,  153.,  162.,  111.],
       [  72.,  111.,  117.,  123.,   84.]])

In [55]: out
Out[55]: 
array([[  4.  ,   4.2 ,   4.5 ,   5.5 ,   6.  ],
       [  6.6 ,   6.75,   7.  ,   8.  ,   8.5 ],
       [ 10.5 ,  11.  ,  12.  ,  13.  ,  13.5 ],
       [ 15.5 ,  16.  ,  17.  ,  18.  ,  18.5 ],
       [ 18.  ,  18.5 ,  19.5 ,  20.5 ,  21.  ]])
```